# Three.js memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I have noticed strange memory leak in three.js (r73).
Step to reproduce:

1)Open following link in Google Chrome ( 46.0.2490.80 m)

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_test_memory

2) Open DevTools -> Profiles - > Take Heap Snapshot. See my screenshot below:

3) Take another heap snapshot after 10 seconds. As you can see the size of heap increased.

[Snaphots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDNKp.png)

But if open this page locally on the computer without any server than heap size will be within the bounds of 5-6 Mb.

Why used memory size permanently increased in example and constant in case of locally page opening?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards, Vasily.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic memory allocation/deallocation example is leaking not only @ the example link: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_test_memory.html but also if you run it from a local webserver @ Three.js r74.

GPU memory utilization is flat.

The example appears to be garbage collected aggressively and appears NOT to be leaking when you are running off the file path and not webserver.

I tried calling more dispose methods in my test:

```js
function render() {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, Math.random() * 64, Math.random() * 32 );

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(createImage());
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, wireframe: true })
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    scene.remove( mesh );    

    mesh.geometry.dispose();
    mesh.material.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
    
    renderer.dispose( mesh );
    renderer.dispose(texture);
    renderer.dispose(mesh.geometry);
    renderer.dispose(mesh.material);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same test in Firefox and did not see any increase in memory consumption. They either fixed the problem in Three.js or it is related to the webgl engine of chrome.

[image: Memory measurements]